# How to properly set st.session_state in streamlit

Tags: python, attributeerror, streamlit

So I have such sample code. As you can see locale setted twice. However I keep getting error:

*AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute "locale". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization*

What is wrong here?

```
import streamlit as st
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Locale:
    ai_role_prefix: str


# --- LOCALE SETTINGS ---
en = Locale(
    ai_role_prefix="base",
)

if 'locale' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.locale = en

if __name__ == "__main__":
    st.session_state.locale = en
    print(st.session_state.locale.ai_role_prefix)
```

Full error stack:

```
C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\python.exe C:/Users/dex/Desktop/gpt4free/AudioChatGPT/src/chat_ui/temp.py
2023-05-12 22:43:37.715 WARNING streamlit.runtime.state.session_state_proxy: Session state does not function when running a script without `streamlit run`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 370, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(widget_id, key)
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 415, in _getitem
    raise KeyError
KeyError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state_proxy.py", line 119, in __getattr__
    return self[key]
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state_proxy.py", line 90, in __getitem__
    return get_session_state()[key]
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\safe_session_state.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    return self._state[key]
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 372, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(_missing_key_error_message(key))
KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "locale". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dex\Desktop\gpt4free\AudioChatGPT\src\chat_ui\temp.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(st.session_state.locale.ai_role_prefix)
  File "C:\Users\dex\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state_proxy.py", line 121, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(_missing_attr_error_message(key))
AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute "locale". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I do not get an error when running your code on Streamlit 1.22 in Python 3.10.11. If you look at your error trace, the very first warning is about the correct way to run a streamlit app. Did you 1. open a terminal at the same location as your file and 2. run it using the command `streamlit run your_file_name.py`?

Comment: @MathCatsAnd  Wow you were right, it works from console  this way "streamlit run .\temp.py" but fails to run from pycharm as standart python code

Comment: post it as an answer)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the first part of the warning:

```
WARNING streamlit.runtime.state.session_state_proxy:
Session state does not function when running a script without `streamlit run`
```

This indicates the script was executed as a normal Python script rather than through the streamlit package.

To run your script as a streamlit app, type in your terminal `streamlit run your_app.py` or `streamlit run path/your_app.py` if you are not located in the same directory as your file.

If for any reason there is still a problem, you can use the more verbose `python -m streamlit run your_app.py`